# String.Split() removes delimiter characters

Tags: vb.net, split, character

I'm trying to create a method that will split a protein sequence based on two characters: `R` and `K`.
My code splits the protein sequence correctly, but then removes either `R` or `K`. I need the program to be able to preserve the delimiters used for splitting the string.

**Example:**

Lets say I have a protein sequence = `GLSDEWQKFEGREGKFWER`

My program will then cut the sequence after there is `R` or `K`.

It should end up like this:

```
GLSDEWQK

FEGR

EGK

FWER
```

---

**My code:**

```
Dim protein As String = "GLSDEWQKFEGREGKFWER"

Dim words As String() = protein.Split(New Char() {"R", "K"})

For Each word As String In words
    Console.WriteLine(word)
Next
```

I am writing this code in Visual Basic .NET Framework 4.7.2 and I want to display results in terminal console.

Comment: That's the way `String.Split` works. If that's not what you want, don't use `String.Split`. The obvious option is to use `IndexOf` and `Substring` in a loop. Before you ask how, read the documentation and put some thought into the logic involved, then have a go for yourself. If you can't do it, then ask how, showing us what you did and telling us what happened when you did it.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please consider [accepting the correct answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1):

`String.Split()` removes the splitter(s) from the resulting array of strings, but you of course want to preserve the full content.

You could loop the chars in the `protein` string (a string is a collection of chars), test the current char to see if it belongs to the array of chars, `{"R"c, "K"c}`, that cause the string to split.

If it doesn't, append the current char to a StringBuilder.
If it does, add the accumulated chars to a `List(Of String)`, which will contain the results when the loop terminates.

You should have all the `Imports` statements already available in your Project. In case you don't add:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
```

```
Dim protein As String = "GLSDEWQKFEGREGKFWER"
Dim splitChars = {"R"c, "K"c}

Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
Dim splitResult As New List(Of String)

For Each c As Char In protein
    sb.Append(c)
    ' If the current char is one of the splitters, add the buffer to the 
    ' results and clear the buffer
    If splitChars.Contains(c) Then
        splitResult.Add(sb.ToString())
        sb.Clear()
    End If
Next
' Take the remainder, if any
If sb.Length > 0 Then splitResult.Add(sb.ToString())
```

Print the list of parts as:

```
For Each section As String In splitResult 
    Console.WriteLine(section)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [RegEx.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) to include the items it was split on, then join the resulting array in pairs:

```
Dim protein As String = "GLSDEWQKFEGREGKFWER"
Dim splitter = New Regex("([KR])")
Dim wordParts = splitter.Split(protein)
' wordParts is now ("GLSDEWQ", "K", "FEG", "R", "EG", "K", "FWE", "R", "")

' join the wordParts in pairs
Dim words As New List(Of String)
For i = 0 To wordParts.Length - 2 Step 2
    words.Add(wordParts(i) & wordParts(i + 1))
Next

' if there was an odd number of parts, the last one needs to be added
If wordParts.Count Mod 2 = 1 AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(wordParts.Last) Then
    words.Add(wordParts.Last)
End If

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, words))
```

Outputs:

```
GLSDEWQK
FEGR
EGK
FWER
```

The `[KR]` is a character group - it'll match on any of the characters in that, and the parentheses `( )` surrounding it make it capture what it matched on.