# How can i make the Regex pick up and display the last part of the sequence

Tags: vb.net

I have copied this code from somewhere but i am trying to adjust it to my needs

```
Function ProteinSegmentation()
        Dim protein As String = "GLSDGEWQQVLNVWGKVEADIAGHGQEVLIRLFTGHPETLEKFDKFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKHGTVVLTALGGILKKKEGHHEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISDAIIHVLHSKHRPGDFGADAQGAMTKALELFRNDIAAKYKELGFQG"
        Dim proteinsplitter = New Regex("([K,R])")
        Dim proteinparts = proteinsplitter.Split(protein)


        Dim words As New List(Of String)
        For i = 0 To proteinparts.Length - 3 Step 3
            words.Add(proteinparts(i) & proteinparts(i + 1))
        Next
        Console.WriteLine("Here is the Protein Sequence :  ")
        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, words))
End Function
```

Now when i run the code it outputs

```
GLSDGEWQQVLNVWGK
VEADIAGHGQEVLIR
LFTGHPETLEK
FDK
FK
HLK
TEAEMK
ASEDLK
K
HGTVVLTALGGILK
K
K
EGHHEAELK
PLAQSHATK
HK
IPIK
YLEFISDAIIHVLHSK
HR
PGDFGADAQGAMTK
ALELFR
NDIAAK
YK
```

however i want it to output the last 6 characters of the full sequence from the start

```
GLSDGEWQQVLNVWGK
VEADIAGHGQEVLIR
LFTGHPETLEK
FDK
FK
HLK
TEAEMK
ASEDLK
K
HGTVVLTALGGILK
K
K
EGHHEAELK
PLAQSHATK
HK
IPIK
YLEFISDAIIHVLHSK
HR
PGDFGADAQGAMTK
ALELFR
NDIAAK
YK
ELGFQG
```

as well however i do not have any experience in debugging so i am not quite sure how to fix it, if you can help pls and thanks

Comment: You haven't *made this code*, you have taken it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66671705/7444103), a question posted by one of your numerous *colleagues*.

Comment: Ok fine its not my code cut would you be able to help with my request ?

Comment: Please show us the output you expect from "the last 6 characters of the full sequence from the start."

Comment: Alright now you can see what I am expecting the code to output versus what it is outputting

Comment: @MarianLime Please see the correction to the [code in my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66675296/1115360). (It would have been better to comment on that and say that it was missing the last entry.)

Comment: yes it very much did